# How to get an array of multiple substrings divided by the same string/symbol/tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a string that is composed of different elements and I need to separate them at another tag in the string.

I used .split() and .pop() which worked great if there is only one element.

```
function getText(fullText, type) {

    var partial = fullText.split('*' + type + '*').pop().split('*/' + type + '*')[0] || 'unknown';
    return partial;
}

var str = "*a*Substring A*/a**b*Substring B*/b**c*Substring C*/c*"

getText(str, a)  // returns 'Substring A'
```

However, I have now encountered multiple elements and in this case it only returns the last element.

```
var str = "*a*Substring A*/a**b*Substring B1*/b**b*Substring B2*/b*"

getText(str, b)  // returns 'Substring B2'
```

How do I get an array with all the substrings between those tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shift()` to remove first element and then use `map()`

```js
function getText(fullText, type) {

    var partial = fullText.split('*' + type + '*') 
    partial.shift();
    for(let i = 0;i<partial.length;i++){
      partial[i] = partial[i].split('*/' + type + '*')[0]
    }
    return partial
}

var str = "*a*Substring A*/a**b*Substring B1*/b**b*Substring B2*/b*"

console.log(getText(str, 'b'))
```

Comment: this too looks neat, but as i mentioned in another comment, i'm using jsx with indesign to be precise and it seems like that doesn't support es6s map since it returns 'Error string: > does not have a value'
can i do this any differently?

Comment: @GabrielRodaEugenBach Does it support `forEach()`?

Comment: @GabrielRodaEugenBach I have replaced `map()` with `for` loop. Make sure to check it.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getText(fullText, type) {
    let re = `\\*${type}\\*(.*?)\\*/${type}\\*`;
    return fullText
      .match(new RegExp(re, 'g'))
      .map(str => str.match(new RegExp(re))[1]);
}

var str = "*a*Substring A*/a* woah *a*Substring A 2*/a*"

x = getText(str, 'a') 

console.log(x)
```

Comment: RegExp is nice for this solution +1.

Comment: this is elegant solution but i'm using jsx with indesign to be precise and it seems like that doesn't support es6s map since it returns 'Error string: > does not have a value'
can i do this any differently?

Comment: `map` is just syntax sugar for a traditional for loop. You could replace it as such. e.g. `for (let i = 0; i < fullText.length; i++) fullText[i] = str.match(...);`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting the last element is because you're using `pop()` which just returns the last element in array:

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

You can read more about it on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) website

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

```js
function getText(fullText, type) {
    var typeStr = "\*" + type + "\*";
    return fullText
        .split('/')
        .filter(item=>item.match(typeStr.replace(/\*/g, '\\*')))
        .map(item=>item
            .substr(item.indexOf(typeStr) + typeStr.length)
            .replace(/\*$/, ''));
}

var str = "*a*Substring A*/a**b*Substring B*/b**c*Substring C*/c*"

console.log(getText(str, 'a'));  // returns 'Substring A'

var str = "*a*Substring A*/a**b*Substring B1*/b**b*Substring B2*/b*"

console.log(getText(str, 'b'));  // returns 'Substring B2'
```

Explaining:

```
// this creates a str with the type to be searched
var typeStr = "\*" + type + "\*";
return fullText
    // this splits all elements in your string
    .split('/')
    // this leaves only elements that match type...
    .filter(item=>item.match(
        // using a regex created with the typeStr created above
        // replace escape the * char to make regex work
        typeStr.replace(/\*/g, '\\*')))
    // now with the remaining parts, alter them as follows...        
    .map(item=>item
        // remove everything before type and type itself
        .substr(item.indexOf(typeStr) + typeStr.length)
        // remove last * char
        .replace(/\*$/, ''));
```

**EDIT**

Reading @junvar's answer I noticed a pattern that I haven't noticed when I answered. That if you substitute * by < or > you have a XML pattern. So it seems to me that the OP has replaced < and > by * in order to mask this is XML parsing. If it is a XML parse, please read the most famous answer in SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2752520

JUST DON'T PARSE XML WITH REGEX.

Answer (score 1):

Using pop() returns the last element in an array(the array that is created when you do your first split)

try:

```
function getText(fullText, type) {
        var partial = fullText.split('*' + type + '*');
        var result = [];
            $.each(partial, function(i, item) {
                 var split = item.split('*/' + type + '*');
                 if (split.length > 1) {
                      result.push(split[0]);
                 }
            });
             return result;
        }
        var str = "*a*Substring A*/a**b*Substring B1*/b**b*Substring B2*/b*";
        console.log(getText(str, 'b'));
```